# Typescript: convert the result from prisma.$queryRaw to a number

Tags: mysql, typescript, prisma

If this SELECT statment returns 123, I need to get the value of 123 from the code below.

```
const rowCount: any = await prisma.$queryRaw`
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MyTable;`

console.log('rowCount: ' + rowCount);
```

But the console.log returns this:

> rowCount: [object Object]

How can I exctract the 123 from the variable rowCount?

Answer (score 1):

[`$queryRaw`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#queryraw) returns an array of objects returned from the query.
You should be able to access the `COUNT(1)` with:

```
const result: any = await prisma.$queryRaw`
SELECT COUNT(1) AS rowCount FROM MyTable;`

console.log('rowCount: ' + result[0].rowCount);
```